# Switch and case option 

Tags: android

I have an activity with 5 buttons. I want to use the switch option. How can I detect which button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Inside onClick(View v):

```
switch(v.getId()){   
  case R.id.nameofbutton: 
    //do this 
    break;  
}
```